# Show different image of the product if the product is grouped

Tags: product-images, grouped-products, magento2.3.4

I want the product image to change on "catalog-category-view" depending on whether the product is 'grouped' or 'simple'.

In Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml the product image is called by

```
<?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
```

which calls image_with_borders.phtml

Here i tried something like that:

```
<?php 
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$is_grouped = $_productCollection ->getTypeId() == 'grouped'; 
if ($is_grouped != 1): 
    echo "yes"; //example
else :                                   
    echo "no";  //example                       
endif;
?>
```

But i always get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTypeId() on
>   null

How can i achieve this? I'm using that sort of code in list.phtml to differentiate between grouped and simple products and it'S working.

Specs: Magento Ver.-2.3.4 | PHP 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check the product is grouped or not.

```
<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'simple' ): ?>
//your code for simple products only
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped' ): ?>
//your code for grouped products only
<?php endif; ?>
```

So on. Place this code in the **catalog/product/view.phtml**

Hope this help you

Thanks...